# Why is the centroid of this parallelogram not $\frac{a+c}{2} = \frac{b+d}{2}$?

Tags: geometry

Let A, B, C, D be points in 3-space with position vectors $a, b, c, d$ respectively such that $b−a=2(c−d)$
.  Assume that the points A, B, C, D are distinct and do not all lie on the same line.

From this context, I figured that ABCD is a parallelogram. I was told $\frac{b+2d}{2}$ is the position vector of the point where the line segments AC and BD intersect but I don't see how the centroid isn't $\frac{b+d}{2}$?

I'm sure it's something to do with the fact that $b−a=2(c−d)$ ⇒ $b+2d=a+2c$ but I don't see what exactly.

Anyone have any tips?

Edit: It's a trapezoid, not a parallelogram that's cleared my confusion now

Comment: Isn't it rather a trapezoid?

Comment: @user376343 oh my god yes I see that now thanks

Comment: You're welcome 

Comment: Anyway, the centroid is not $b+2d\over2$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Yes I understand that now because I thought ABCD was a parallelogram